# LVM is not supported yet

Tags: 12.04, gparted, lvm

I have been forced to re-installed 12.04 due to virtualbox/grub problems. And I selected the LVM option as I have read its better for Virtual Machines.

Ubuntu is installed and running fine but in GParted I get the following error:

[image]

Is this because GParted can't understand it, Or is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gparted can not manage LVM. What are you trying to do ?

See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm and/or update your question.

Comment: I'm not trying to do anything, I was just wanting to make sure it was just GParted having the problem and nothing worse. Thanks

Comment: OK, great. If you need help with LVM come on back.